# Can I use past continuous with 'for'?

Tags: time, past-continuous, for

a. Jane **had been studying** *for 5 hours* when her parents came home.

b. Jane **was studying** *for 5 hours* when her parents came home.

I think 'a' is ok, but what about 'b'? As a non-native, I wonder 'b' is correct, especially in grammar. Can I use past continous with 'for'?

---

Addition

A native teacher replied to me just a while ago that 'b' is not correct.
"In spoken informal English, yes, you can use the Past Continuous and there will no misunderstanding.
However, in a test, if you want to be perfectly grammatically correct, you should use the Past Perfect Tense. A well-spoken native speaker would also use the Past Perfect Continuous if they mention the length of time."

What's your opinion about this? Is 'b' natural or awkward?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Past continuous with "for" is okay.  However, "b" is not correct.

"B" is not correct because of "when".  Did Jane's parents need 5 hours to arrive at home?  No, so Jane's studying happened in the 5 hours before they arrived.  Since the studying was before a past event, the sentence needs to be "a", not "b".

Use past continuous with a time expression.

Correct:

"I was tossing and turning all night."

"Jane was studying for 5 hours yesterday."

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct and understandable and have the same meaning that

> Jane studied for 5 hours before her parents came home.